# Transition-group block emits from components inside

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Maybe anyone knows how to fix that

i've got a Cart.vue component with simple content below

```
<script>
import CartItem from './CartItem.vue';
export default{
    mounted(){},
    props:{
        userCart: Object
    },components:{
        CartItem
    },
    data:()=>({}),
    methods:{},
}
</script>
<template>
   <div class="userCart">
     <transition-group tag="ul">
       <cart-item v-for="item in userCart" :key="item.id" :item="item"></cart-item>
     </transition-group>
   </div>
</template>
```

And another component named CartItem.vue with code

```
<script>
export default{
    mounted(){},
    props:{
        item: Object
    },data:()=>({}),
    methods:{},
    watch:{}
}
</script>

<template>
    <li class="cart-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
        {{ item.name }} {{ item.id }}
        <button @click="$parent.$emit('doStaff',item.id)">doStaff</button>
    </li>
</template>
```

and now i can't find any solutions about why WRAP transition-group block my emits on itself and to pass emit to a parent(root) component i need to add @customEvent="customEvent" on transition-group wrapper because component CartItem can't pass through UserCart to App.vue

sorry for my english, i'm from russia

im try to delete component cartItem and itterate all in userCart but i need to save qty for every goods in cart

Comment: It's bad practice to use `$parent` and your problem is one reason why.  You should emit from child to parent, then parent to grandparent.  You also don't _need_ to add the event listener to `<transition-group>`, you can instead put it on `<cart-item>` which would make more sense.

Comment: but why i cant pass through the "middle" component

Comment: Because of the way transition-group is architected, you just can't.  You'll have to ask the Vue team why they made it that way, but like I said, using `$parent` is bad practice. It tightly couples components together and is an anti-pattern. There's probably no good reason why it should be used so transition-group preventing the use of `$parent` is not a big concern. Simply use an alternative strategy